# Can anyone point out the mistake?

Tags: sql-server

Logic for creating the function

If the employee has completed one year from the date which he is hired,  salary has to be incremented by 1k.
Like that for every year completion, salary has to increment by 1k.

Comment: You don't show us your attempt of creating this function, please include it in the question, also show us some sample data

Comment: @GuidoG can't upload image because new user

Comment: @SreehariPV, you do not need to upload image. Copy-paste your code as text

Comment: Please DO NOT upload an image with your sample data, upload it as text

Comment: @RhythmWasaLurker i'll create table valued then

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct you want a function that will calculate the new salary of employees based on the hiredate and the current date

A function like that can look like this

```
create function EmployeeSalaryIncrement(@hiredate date, @sal int) returns int as
begin
     declare @years int = datediff(year, @hiredate, getdate())
     return @sal + (@years * 1000)
end
```

Please find a [complete example](https://dbfiddle.uk/NyIWf8VF) here, check it out if this is what you need

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the calculation is a direct calculation on data from a single table an Inline Table Valued Function (iTVF) might yield better performance. Normally this is the case.

As such the function can be:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.tvf_EmployeeSalaryIncrement( @EmplCode int )
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (  
  SELECT
    e.EMPNO
  , Datediff( year, e.HIREDATE, Sysdatetime() ) * 1000
    + e.SAL AS CurrentSalary
  FROM
    EMP AS e
  WHERE
      e.EMPNO = @EmplCode
);
```

This can be used like:

```
SELECT
  ...
FROM EMP AS e
  INNER JOIN tvf_EmployeeSalaryIncrement( e.EMPNO )
;
```

In all honesty using a function just because there is a calculation seems overkill to me. A much simpler way is a simple view that takes the columns from table EMP and adds the calculation (as single line) to the output.
This works unless the date to use as comparison date shall be flexible. In this case this comparison date can be added to the function.

Additional background for Table Valued Functions:

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-basics-of-itvfs